# generate table of contents for markdown out of latex .toc-file

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

I have a latex-generated .toc file with the table of contents of a large document. I would like to extract the TOC to a (github-)markdown list e.g. with pandoc.

e.g. I have

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Aim and Motivation}{1}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}State of the art}{1}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Outline}{1}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Fundamentals}{2}{chapter.2}
...
```

in my .toc file.

And would like to get something like this

```
1. Introduction
  1.1. Aim and Motivation
  1.2. State-of-the-art
  1.3. Outline
2. Fundamentals
```

Another alternative would be to extract this information (without the content) out of the tex-file directly. However, I could not get this working and I also think it would be more error-prone.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Another alternative would be to extract this information out of the tex-file directly.

Pandoc can do that:

```
$ pandoc -s --toc input.tex -o output.md
```

To exclude the document body content, you'll have to use a custom pandoc markdown template:

```
$ pandoc -D markdown > mytemplate.md
```

Modify `mytemplate.md` to keep `$toc$` and remove `$body$`, then use with `pandoc --template mytemplate.md ...`

If you want to customize it more I would recommend outputting to html (`pandoc -t html`) instead of markdown, then write a small script that traverses the html DOM and does your numbering etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc unfortunately creates an empty markdown file in my case. I have created an open source cli tool, that performs that conversion:
https://github.com/MaaxGr/latex-toc-markdown

Download the binary (see README of GitHub Page) and execute the following command:

```
./latex-toc-markdown Input.toc Output.toc
```

The Output file will look the following:

```
* 1 Introduction
  * 1.1 Aim and Motivation
  * 1.2 State of the art
  * 1.3 Outline
* 2 Fundamentals
```